# Element Collection Not persisting to the datbase after transaction ends

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a UserRoot entity. The UserRoot is used to access all the user modules, including @ElementCollection FriendsList.

when I try to add a friend to the friends list, after calling .persist and testing from within the method the friend appears to be persisted. But I try to call another test endpoint that retrieves the list and prints it and it says that the size is 0. I must be missing some simple command in the adding of UserRoot to friends list. any suggestions? I've tried merging the data, ive tried flushing the data before I persist it, but nothing seems to work. do I need to rethink the method that I use to add friends?

> I should note that the way I had it before - working - the friendslist contained a list of seperate identities from the UserRoot, a PublicIdentity which wasn't actually linked to the UserRoot, but it had an ID that matched the user root. JPA seemed to like this way better, but it resulted in having to search the database another time for each time a user made a request. I'm trying to find a way around that.

this is the error im getting when attempting to flush before committing:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute statement [n/a] 
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '40' for key 'UK_th3hlgtbty5m4reql4gqugbc9'
```

```
package tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.jpa.friends;

import lombok.Data;
import tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.jpa.user.root.UserRoot;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
public class FriendsList implements Serializable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = -3108516247756660434L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long flID;

    @OneToOne
    private UserRoot userRoot;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<UserRoot> usersFriends;

    @GeneratedValue
    private long listId;




    public void addFriend(UserRoot userRoot) {
        usersFriends.add(userRoot);
    }

    public FriendsList(){
        usersFriends = new ArrayList<>();

    }

}


package tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.jpa.user.root;

import lombok.Data;
import tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.jpa.friends.FriendsList;
import tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.jpa.user.notification.UserAlertModule;
import tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.jpa.user.profile.PublicPost;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
public class UserRoot implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long userRootId;

    @Column
    private String identity;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userRoot")
    @JoinColumn
    private UserAccountDetails accountDetails;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userRoot")
    @JoinColumn
    private FriendsList friendsList;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userRoot")
    @JoinColumn
    private UserAlertModule userAlertModule;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<PublicPost> publicPosts;

    public UserRoot(){
        publicPosts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public PublicPost addPost(PublicPost publicPost) {
        publicPosts.add(publicPost);
        return publicPost;
    }


}



 @Override
    public void acceptFriendRequest(long id, UserRoot currentlyActiveUserRoot) {

        String currentlyActiveUserRootIdentity = currentlyActiveUserRoot.getIdentity();
        log.info("currentlyActiveUserRootIdentity = {}", currentlyActiveUserRootIdentity);
        log.info("alertId to accept is = {}", id);
        log.info("accepting friend request ....");

        UserAlert alert = userMessagingService.acknowledgeAlert(id);


        String usernameToAdd = alert.getFromUsername();
        log.info("username to add = {}", usernameToAdd);
        String pidToAdd = alert.getSubject();
        log.info("finding user in userRootRepository by username = {}", usernameToAdd);
        UserRoot friendToAdd = userAccountAccessService.accessAccount(usernameToAdd);


        log.info("geting friends list from friend to add");
        FriendsList friendsFriendsList = friendToAdd.getFriendsList();
        log.info("getting currently active user root , getting friends list");
        FriendsList currentlyActiveUsersFriendsList = currentlyActiveUserRoot.getFriendsList();

        // beginning transaction
        log.info("beginning first transaction -- add self to New Friends' Friends List >");
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        log.info("adding current user to friends' friends list ....");
        friendsFriendsList.addFriend(currentlyActiveUserRoot);
        log.info("committing first transaction");
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        log.info("beginning second transaction");
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();


        log.info("adding friend to friends list");
        currentlyActiveUsersFriendsList.addFriend(friendToAdd);


        log.info("committing second transaction ....");
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();


        log.info("second transaction successfully committed!");

        log.info("beginning test >");

        log.info("CURRENTLY ACTIVE USER ROOTS FRIENDS LIST CONTENTS: \n");
        String currentIdentity = currentlyActiveUsersFriendsList.getUserRoot().getIdentity();
        log.info("current identity: {}",currentIdentity);
        currentlyActiveUsersFriendsList.getUsersFriends().forEach(friend->
                System.out.println(friend.getIdentity()));

        String friendsIdentity = friendsFriendsList.getUserRoot().getIdentity();
        log.info("friends identity = {}",friendsIdentity);
        friendsFriendsList.getUsersFriends().forEach(friend->
                System.out.println(friend.getIdentity()));

        log.info("test complete");
        log.info("accept friend request complete! returning ....");
    }
```